# What are the “~orig” files in OS X?

Tags: macos

In the `/etc` folder of my system (OS X 10.8.2) I see a bunch of files named with the "`~orig`" suffix (e.g `hosts~orig`, `passwd~orig`, etc). What are these?

Comment: Probably backups made by some program. Did you edit these manually or do you have something installed that modifies them automatically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those are the leftovers of OS upgrade.

The OS X upgrade saves previous configurations that's going to be changed.

The date of ~orig file should correspond with the OS upgrade.